# SapUI5 and Odata Service issue

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-gateway

I am trying to consume Gateway OData Services in sapui5 app.

Metadata - `/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZUSER_MANAGE_SRV/$metadata` as follows:
[image]

UserdataSet - `/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZUSER_MANAGE_SRV/UserdataSet` as follows:
[image]

**MY CODE**

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("http://Host:Port/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZUSER_MANAGE_SRV", false,"USER","Password");
        
    var app = new sap.m.App("myApp",{});
        
    var oTable = new sap.m.Table("list1", {
                                growing: true,
                                growingThreshold: 200,
                                //mode: sap.m.ListMode.SingleSelect,
                                columns: [
                                    new sap.m.Column({
                                        header: new sap.m.Label({text: "ID"})
                                    }),
                                    new sap.m.Column({
                                        header: new sap.m.Label({text: "First Name"})
                                    }),
                                    new sap.m.Column({
                                        header: new sap.m.Label({text: "Last Name"})
                                    })
                                ],
                                items: {
                                    path: "/UserdataSet",
                                    template: new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                                        cells: [
                                            new sap.m.Input({value: "{EUname}"}),
                                            new sap.m.Input({value: "{EFirstname}"}),
                                            new sap.m.Input({value: "{ELastname}"})
                                        ]
                                    })
                                }
                            });    
    oTable.setModel(oModel);
    var page1 = new sap.m.Page("page1",{
        title: "App",
        content: [oTable]
    });
    
    app.addPage(page1);
    
    return app;
```

Getting error as - `uncaught exception: [object Object]`.

Detailed Error:
[image]

Please help, whats wrong with my code?

Comment: The error appears to be from metadata call. Can you check in network tab if the metadata call loaded correctly.

Comment: Hi @Veeraraghavan, I didn't see any metadata call under network tab. Can you please tell me is there anything else I can do

Answer (score 0):

Your OData service needs to be on the same server or needs to appear to be coming from the same server as your UI5 application. If it's not on the same server you should get Gateway to produce CORS headers.

Please find more info on CORS and how to get Gateway to produce these headers here: http://scn.sap.com/community/gateway/blog/2014/09/23/solve-cors-with-gateway-and-chrome

Answer (score 0):

The Error is not very clear maybe chrome will show an more detailed error in this case.

If your application server and odata service are not from the same origin, the SOP (same origin policy) restricts this action.

Two pages have the same origin if the protocol, port and host are the same for both pages.

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy for more details.

you can start chrome with `--disable-web-security` flag:
In CMD:

```
C:/<path to chrome app>/chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

***!!! ONLY FOR DEVELOPMENT REASONS !!!***